# List of tables used in a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a large project in QGIS with about 50 tables and 100s of layers based upon those tables. It has become a bit unwieldy need to tidy it up a bit, combining, replacing or deleting some of these.

I'm not familiar with PyGIS and I've found a script to list the layers used in a project, but is there a way in PyGIS to get a list of tables used and a list of layers associated with each table?

Comment: Did you try the Plugin "Project Report" which list all layers and also Joins and Relations to tables if used? see https://github.com/sigdeletras/project-reports-qgis-plugin

Comment: Each table has columns related to a plan name and I use filters in the layer to select elements for a particular plan

Comment: What kind of tables is it, geopackages?

Comment: It is a geopackage

Comment: I've tried Project Report but I get an error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/peter/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\NWW 2016 Onwards/python/plugins\project_report\project_report_dockwidget.py", line 108, in check_folder
    if os.path.exists(self.project.report_directory):
AttributeError: 'ProjectReportDockWidget' object has no attribute 'project'

Comment: You can also try "Layerboard" plugin. Not very maintained, but you can try quickly, it will display a table with all datasource.

Comment: Layerboard crashed QGIS 3.32

Answer (score 3):

You might need to modify this a bit to fit your needs.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd #https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
sources = dd(list)

for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    #For each layer in the layer tree
    table = layer.source() #Extract its source
    if "subset" in table: #If there is a filter on the layer, extract only the gpkg an layer name, not the filter 
        table = table.split("|subset")[0]
    sources[table].append(layer.name())
    

for table, layernames in sources.items():
    #For each table, and list of layers based on it
    print(f"There are {len(layernames)} layer(s) based on the table {table}:")
    for layername in layernames:
        print("   ", layername)
    print("\n")
```

[image]

Comment: With a little tweaking, that's just what I needed, thanks very much

Comment: Nice! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)